# What does “actual food” mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, phrase-meaning

I found this phrase in an article of *The New York Review of Books*, June 11, 2020, named “The Sickness in Our Food Supply”. The original text is

> The renaissance of home cooking, and baking, is one of the happier
> consequences of the lockdown, good news both for our health and for
> farmers who grow **actual food**, as opposed to commodities like corn
> and soy.

I have searched this phrase in google, but the results were generally relevant to “actual food cost and theoretical food cost”. So corn and soy are not actual food? What does “actual food” mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The passage's use of "actual food" is given away in the final part of the sentence. Usually when we refer to farmers, we're talking about those who raise crops and tend stock for direct food consumption. However, there are farms whose production of crops is used for other, more industrial, purposes. The products of which (such as corn syrup) may be indirectly used in the creation of other foodstuffs.

So "actual food" is refering to just those crops (vegetables, fruit, wheat, etc) that are grown for direct human consumption.

Comment: The source article is paywalled, but it is by Michael Pollan, which leads me to expect that his habitual exclusion of processed foods from the category "food" is at work here, as in his famous advice, “Eat food. Not too much. Mostly plants.”

Comment: Also, soy and corn are heavily GMO. Corn is used for auto ethanol, and soybean oil for fast-food fryers.

Comment: One wonders, then if the wheat farmer’s crop that gets milled into flour counts. Surely my grandmother thought it had something to do with food.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, corn and soy do constitute food, in the standard sense of the word *food*. This use of the word *food* is deliberately nonstandard; it belongs to the jargon of the movement that promotes a particular way of thinking about food. As the review of Michael Pollan's book *Food Rules* in the *Houston Chronicle* (reproduced on Pollan's own [website](https://michaelpollan.com/reviews/how-to-eat/)) summarises it:

> By “food” Pollan means real food, not creations of the food-industrial complex. Real food doesn’t have a long ingredient list, isn’t advertised on TV, and it doesn’t contain stuff like maltodextrin or sodium tripolyphosphate. Real food is things that your great-grandmother (or someone’s great-grandmother) would recognize.

Refusing to apply the word *food* to industrially processed food is a part of this movement's strategy to discourage people from eating it. Regardless of whether one supports or opposes the aims of the movement, one has to acknowledge that its way of using the word is bound to be confusing to those, such as the OP, who encounter it for the first time.

Corn (maize) and soy are used in the text as examples because they are usually grown on a large scale and industrially processed. If you bought a small amount of them on a local market, directly from the farmer who grew them, they would count as food, even in this, highly idiosyncratic, sense of the word.

(This answer is an elaboration of the point that was first made by Professor Donovan in a comment.)